# Infinite loop in relationship?

Tags: prolog

I will give a simple example to illustrate my problem.

Lets say I have a simple knowledge base like this:

```
connected(scotland,england).
connected(england, wales).
```

Now I want to query whether or not england is connected to scotland, because the predicate is should be true vice-versa, so I add this rule:

```
connected(X, Y) :- connected(Y,X).
```

And connected(england,scotland) returns True.

However a query like connected(a,b) keeps to program in a infinite loop. I am not sure how to modify my rule.

Comment: Don't use the same name for your rule as you do your facts.

Comment: @lurker ok so making the name of the rule connected2 resolves it and I can see why the recursion stops. But, it's not possible to have it the same name? It's kind of weird that you can write connected(scotland,england) but not connected(england,scotland)

Comment: You can write `connected2(X, Y) :- connected(X, Y) ; connected(Y, X).`. Then `connected2(scotland, england)` and `connected2(england, scotland)` are both true. If you'd rather query if two places are `connected` rather than `connected2` then use `connected` for your rule and pick a different name for your facts.